# Shading in webgl

Tags: javascript, html, webgl

I have been trying to create shading in webgl just like in this image: where we can see a cone, a sphere, and a light (which we can change his position with the sliders).

[image]

I've tried to write some code in the html file by seeing multiple examples of shading from some webgl tutoring sites, but right now, I can't even see the shapes. It's sure that I'm doing something wrong, but I just don't know where. Here's my code and I also included a link because it contains multiple files. Thanks in advance.

Link: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/cd0f66f2e2866c0d118e95b02e01cb0520200923203442/274553

```html
<html>

<head>
<title>Light and Shading</title>
<meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1'>

<!-- CSS Styles //-->
<link href='css/style.css'   type='text/css' rel='stylesheet'>
<link href='css/desert.css'  type='text/css' rel='stylesheet'/>
<link href='css/colorpicker.css'  type='text/css' rel='stylesheet'/>
<link href='css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' />

<!-- JavaScript Libraries //-->
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/gl-matrix-min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js'></script> 
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/prettify.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/utils.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/colorpicker.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/codeview.js'></script>

<script id="shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
    attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;
    attribute vec3 aVertexNormal;

    // matrice model-view combinee.
    uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;

    // matrice de projection
    uniform mat4 uPMatrix;

    // matrice des normales.
    uniform mat3 uNMatrix;

    // position de la lumiere.
    uniform vec3 uLightPosition;

    // La normale transformee
    varying vec3 vNormal;

    // la direction vertex-lumiere
    varying vec3 vLightRay;

    // la direction camera-vertex
    varying vec3 vEyeVec;

    uniform vec4 uLightAmbient;
    uniform vec4 uLightDiffuse;
    uniform vec4 uLightSpecular;

    uniform vec4 uMaterialAmbient;
    uniform vec4 uMaterialDiffuse;
    uniform vec4 uMaterialSpecular;


    void main(void) {


    vec4 ambientProduct= uLightAmbient* uMaterialAmbient;
    vec4 diffuseProduct= uLightDiffuse*uMaterialDiffuse;
    vec4 specularProduct= uLightSpecular*uMaterialSpecular;

    vec3 pos = (uMVMatrix*vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0)).xyz;


    // position de l'oeil/camera.
    const vec3 eyePosition = vec3(0,0,-40);

    //Transformed normal position
    vNormal = normalize((uNMatrix* aVertexNormal).xyz) ;

    //Transformed light position
    vec4 light = uMVMatrix * vec4(uLightPosition,1.0);

    vec3 lightPos = (uMVMatrix * light).xyz;

    //Light position
    vLightRay = normalize(pos - lightPos);

    //Vector Eye
    vEyeVec = -normalize(pos);


    //Final vertex position
    gl_Position = uMVMatrix*uPMatrix* vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);

    }
</script>

<script id="shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
    #ifdef GL_ES
    precision highp float;
    #endif

    varying vec3 vNormal;
    varying vec3 vLightRay;
    varying vec3 vEyeVec;

    uniform vec4 ambientProduct;
    uniform vec4 diffuseProduct;
    uniform vec4 specularProduct;
    uniform float uShininess;

    void main(void)
    {

    vec4 diffuse = max(dot( vNormal,vLightRay), 0.0) * diffuseProduct;
    vec3 H = normalize(vLightRay+vEyeVec);
    vec4 specular =
    pow(max(dot(vNormal, H), 0.0), uShininess) * specularProduct;
    if (dot(vLightRay, vNormal) < 0.0)
    specular = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    vec4 fColor = ambientProduct + diffuse + specular;
    fColor.a = 1.0;
    gl_FragColor =fColor;

    }
</script>



<script id='code-js' type="text/javascript">

var gl = null; // WebGL context
var prg = null; // The program (shaders)
var c_width = 0; // Variable to store the width of the canvas
var c_height = 0; // Variable to store the height of the canvas

var mvMatrix = mat4.create(); // The Model-View matrix
var pMatrix = mat4.create(); // The projection matrix
var nMatrix =  mat4.create();      // The normal matrix

var distance = -40;
var animateFlag = false;

var objects = [];   

/**
* The program contains a series of instructions that tell the Graphic Processing Unit (GPU)
* what to do with every vertex and fragment that we pass it. 
* The vertex shader and the fragment shader together are called the program.
*/
function initProgram() {
var fragmentShader      = utils.getShader(gl, "shader-fs");
var vertexShader        = utils.getShader(gl, "shader-vs");

prg = gl.createProgram();
gl.attachShader(prg, vertexShader);
gl.attachShader(prg, fragmentShader);
gl.linkProgram(prg);

if (!gl.getProgramParameter(prg, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
alert("Could not initialise shaders");
}

gl.useProgram(prg);

prg.aVertexPosition     = gl.getAttribLocation(prg, "aVertexPosition");
prg.aVertexNormal       = gl.getAttribLocation(prg, "aVertexNormal");

prg.uPMatrix            = gl.getUniformLocation(prg, "uPMatrix");
prg.uMVMatrix           = gl.getUniformLocation(prg, "uMVMatrix");
prg.uNMatrix            = gl.getUniformLocation(prg, "uNMatrix");


prg.uMaterialAmbient    = gl.getUniformLocation(prg, "uMaterialAmbient");
prg.uMaterialDiffuse    = gl.getUniformLocation(prg, "uMaterialDiffuse");
prg.uMaterialSpecular   = gl.getUniformLocation(prg, "uMaterialSpecular");
prg.uShininess          = gl.getUniformLocation(prg, "uShininess");


prg.uLightPosition      = gl.getUniformLocation(prg, "uLightPosition");
prg.uLightAmbient       = gl.getUniformLocation(prg, "uLightAmbient");
prg.uLightDiffuse       = gl.getUniformLocation(prg, "uLightDiffuse");
prg.uLightSpecular      = gl.getUniformLocation(prg, "uLightSpecular");
}


function initLights(){
//Light uniforms
gl.uniform3fv(prg.uLightPosition,[4.5,3.0,15.0]);        
gl.uniform4f(prg.uLightAmbient ,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
gl.uniform4f(prg.uLightDiffuse,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
gl.uniform4f(prg.uLightSpecular,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);

//Object Uniforms
gl.uniform4f(prg.uMaterialAmbient, 0.1,0.1,0.1,1.0);
gl.uniform4f(prg.uMaterialDiffuse, 0.5,0.8,0.1,1.0);
gl.uniform4f(prg.uMaterialSpecular, 0.6,0.6,0.6,1.0);
gl.uniform1f(prg.uShininess, 200.0);

}


/**
* Creates an AJAX request to load the scene asynchronously
*/
function loadScene(){
loadObject('models/plane.json');
loadObject('models/cone.json','cone');
loadObject('models/sphere.json','sphere');
loadObject('models/smallsph.json','lightsource');
}

function getObject(alias){
for(var i=0; i<objects.length; i++){
if (alias == objects[i].alias) return objects[i];
}
return null;
}

/**
* Ajax and JSON in action
*/ 

function loadObject(filename,alias){
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    console.info('Requesting ' + filename);
    request.open("GET",filename);
    
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
        if(request.status == 404) {
            console.info(filename + ' does not exist');
        }
        else {
var o = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
o.alias = (alias==null)?'none':alias;
            handleLoadedObject(filename,o);
        }
    }
    }
    request.send();
}

/**
* Creates the buffers that contain the geometry of the object
*/
function handleLoadedObject(filename,object) {
    
    console.info(filename + ' has been retrieved from the server');
    
    var vertexBufferObject = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferObject);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(object.vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    
        
    var normalBufferObject = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, normalBufferObject);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(calcNormals(object.vertices, object.indices)), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    
    var indexBufferObject = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBufferObject);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(object.indices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
        
    
    object.vbo = vertexBufferObject;
    object.ibo = indexBufferObject;
    object.nbo = normalBufferObject;

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,null);
    
    objects.push(object);
} 

/**
* Main rendering function. Called every 500ms according to WebGLStart function (see below)
*/
function drawScene() {
    gl.clearColor(0.3,0.3,0.3, 1.0);
    gl.clearDepth(100.0);
    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.depthFunc(gl.LEQUAL);
    gl.viewport(0, 0, c_width, c_height);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    mat4.perspective(60, c_width / c_height, 0.1, 1000.0, pMatrix);

    try{
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(prg.aVertexPosition);
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(prg.aVertexNormal);
        for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++){
            var object = objects[i];
            mat4.identity(mvMatrix);
            mat4.translate(mvMatrix, [0.0, 0.0, distance]); //Sets the camera to a reasonable distance to view the part
            mat4.rotate(mvMatrix, 30*Math.PI/180, [1,0,0]);
            mat4.rotate(mvMatrix, angle*Math.PI/180, [0,1,0]);
            if (object.alias == 'lightsource'){
                var lightPos = gl.getUniform(prg, prg.uLightPosition);
                mat4.translate(mvMatrix,lightPos);
                
            }
            
            gl.uniformMatrix4fv(prg.uMVMatrix, false, mvMatrix);
            gl.uniformMatrix4fv(prg.uPMatrix, false, pMatrix);
            mat4.set(mvMatrix, nMatrix);
            mat4.inverse(nMatrix);
            mat4.transpose(nMatrix);
            
            gl.uniformMatrix4fv(prg.uNMatrix, false, nMatrix);
            gl.uniform4fv(prg.uMaterialAmbient, object.ambient);
            gl.uniform4fv(prg.uMaterialDiffuse, object.diffuse);
            gl.uniform4fv(prg.uMaterialSpecular, object.specular);
            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, object.vbo);
            gl.vertexAttribPointer(prg.aVertexPosition, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
            gl.enableVertexAttribArray(prg.aVertexPosition);
            
            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, object.nbo);
            gl.vertexAttribPointer(prg.aVertexNormal, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
            gl.enableVertexAttribArray(prg.aVertexNormal);
            
            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, object.ibo);
            gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, object.indices.length, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT,0);
            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
        }
    }
    catch(err){
        alert(err);
        message(err.description);
    }
}






var lastTime = 0;
var angle = 0;
/**
* Updates the angle of rotation by a little bit each time
*/
function animate() {
    var timeNow = new Date().getTime();
    if (lastTime != 0) {
        var elapsed = timeNow - lastTime;
        if (animateFlag) angle += (90 * elapsed) / 10000.0;
    }
    lastTime = timeNow;
}

/**
* Render Loop
*/
function renderLoop() {
    requestAnimFrame(renderLoop);
    drawScene();
animate();
}

/**
* Entry point. This function is invoked when the page is loaded
*/
function runWebGLApp() {
//Obtains a WebGL context
gl = utils.getGLContext("canvas-element-id");
//Initializes the program (shaders) 
    initProgram();
    //Initializes lights
    initLights();
    //Load Scene
loadScene();
    //Renders the scene!
    renderLoop();
}
</script>
</head>

<body onLoad='runWebGLApp()'>
<div id='top'>

<div id='contents'>
<div id='canvasContainer'>
<canvas id='canvas-element-id' width='480' height='400'>
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas element.
</canvas>
</div>
</div>

<div id='bottom'>
<table style='padding=0px'>
<tr>
<td>X:</td><td id='slider-x-value' width='30px'>4.5</td><td width='150px'><div id='slider-x'/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Y:</td><td id='slider-y-value'  width='30px'>3.0</td><td width='150px'><div id='slider-y'/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Z:</td> <td id='slider-z-value'  width='30px'>15.0</td><td width='150px'><div id='slider-z'/></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<script>cview.run(cview.MODE_VIEW);</script>
<script> 
$('#slider-shininess').slider({value:200, min:1, max:300, step:1, slide:updateShininess});
$('#slider-x').slider({value:4.5, min:-50, max:50, step:0.1, slide:updateLightPosition, change:updateLightPosition});
$('#slider-y').slider({value:3.0, min:0, max:50, step:0.1, slide:updateLightPosition, change:updateLightPosition});
$('#slider-z').slider({value:15.0, min:-50, max:50, step:0.1, slide:updateLightPosition, change:updateLightPosition});


$('#animate-btn').button();
$('#animate-btn').click(
function(){
    if ($('#animate-btn:checked').val()==null){
        animateFlag = false;
    }
    else{
        animateFlag = true;
    }
});
function updateShininess(){
    var v = $('#slider-shininess').slider("value");
    gl.uniform1f(prg.uShininess, v);
    $('#slider-shininess-value').html(v);
}



function updateLightPosition(){
    var x = $('#slider-x').slider("value");
    var y = $('#slider-y').slider("value");
    var z = $('#slider-z').slider("value");
    gl.uniform3fv(prg.uLightPosition, [x,y,z]);
    $('#slider-x-value').html(x);
    $('#slider-y-value').html(y);
    $('#slider-z-value').html(z);
}


function updateDistance(){
    var d = $('#slider-distance').slider("value");
    $('#slider-distance-value').html(distance);
    distance = -d;
}



function updateObjectColor(alias, r,g,b){
    var object = getObject(alias);
    if (object != null){
        object.diffuse = [r,g,b,1.0];
    }

}

$('#colorSelectorSphere').ColorPicker({
onSubmit: function(hsb, hex, rgb, el) {
        $(el).val(hex);
        $(el).ColorPickerHide();

    },
color: '#00ff00',
onShow: function (colpkr) {
        $(colpkr).fadeIn(500);
        return false;
    },
onHide: function (colpkr) {
        $(colpkr).fadeOut(500);
        return false;
    },
onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
        $('#colorSelectorSphere div').css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);
        updateObjectColor('sphere',rgb.r/256,rgb.g/256,rgb.b/256);
    },
    
onBeforeShow: function (colpkr) {
        $(this).ColorPickerSetColor('rgb(0.5,0.8,0.1)');
    }
})

$('#colorSelectorCone').ColorPicker({
onSubmit: function(hsb, hex, rgb, el) {
        $(el).val(hex);
        $(el).ColorPickerHide();

    },
color: '#00ff00',
onShow: function (colpkr) {
        $(colpkr).fadeIn(500);
        return false;
    },
onHide: function (colpkr) {
        $(colpkr).fadeOut(500);
        return false;
    },
onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
        $('#colorSelectorCone div').css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);
        updateObjectColor('cone',rgb.r/256,rgb.g/256,rgb.b/256);
    },
    
onBeforeShow: function (colpkr) {
        $(this).ColorPickerSetColor('rgb(0.8,0.1,0.5)');
    }
}) 


// Calcule les normales des vertex. La normale de chaque vertex est
// la moyenne des triangles voisins.
//
// vertices: la liste des vertex.
// ind: la liste des indices.
// retour: la liste des normales par vertex.
function calcNormals(vertices, ind){
  var x=0; 
  var y=1;
  var z=2;
    var v1 = [], v2 = [], thisNormal = [];

    // initialiser la liste des normales.
  var ns = [];
  for(var i=0;i<vertices.length;i++)
    {
    ns[i]=0.0;
  }

  for(var i=0;i<ind.length;i=i+3){
    //v1 = p1 - p0
    v1[x] = vertices[3*ind[i+1]+x] - vertices[3*ind[i]+x];
    v1[y] = vertices[3*ind[i+1]+y] - vertices[3*ind[i]+y];
    v1[z] = vertices[3*ind[i+1]+z] - vertices[3*ind[i]+z];

    // v2 = p2 - p1
    v2[x] = vertices[3*ind[i+2]+x] - vertices[3*ind[i]+x];
    v2[y] = vertices[3*ind[i+2]+y] - vertices[3*ind[i]+y];
    v2[z] = vertices[3*ind[i+2]+z] - vertices[3*ind[i]+z];            

    // N = v2 x v1 (cross product).
    thisNormal[x] = v1[y]*v2[z] - v1[z]*v2[y];
    thisNormal[y] = v1[z]*v2[x] - v1[x]*v2[z];
    thisNormal[z] = v1[x]*v2[y] - v1[y]*v2[x];

    for(j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            // N += thisNormal. on additionne les normales. 
      ns[3*ind[i+j]+x] =  ns[3*ind[i+j]+x] + thisNormal[x];
      ns[3*ind[i+j]+y] =  ns[3*ind[i+j]+y] + thisNormal[y];
      ns[3*ind[i+j]+z] =  ns[3*ind[i+j]+z] + thisNormal[z];
    }
  }

  // Normalisation.
  for(var i=0;i<vertices.length;i=i+3){ 

    var nn=[];
        var len = 0;
        for(var j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            nn[j] = ns[i+j];
            len += nn[j] * nn[j];
        }

        // La norme de la normale.
        len = Math.sqrt(len);
    if (len == 0) 
            len = 0.00001;

        for(var j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        ns[i+j] = nn[j] / len;

        console.log(len);
  }

  return ns;
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you are just starting this is way too much code to get a sphere and cone on the screen. Loading models? That's arguably an advanced topic. I suggest you use some [different and more modern tutorials](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-lighting-point.html) (lots of things in the code suggest this tutorial is outdated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, there are too many issues to cover. Trying to get your code work. First you really need to learn how to make a minimal repo. The code you posted doesn't run, references several scripts that don't exist, and data that doesn't exist.

The tutorial the code is based off appears to be old. No one uses XMLHttpRequest in 2020. There's no such function as `requestAnimFrame` it's `requestAnimationFrame`. I think that's left over from a polyfill from like 2011. It's still using `<body onload="">` which few use anymore. It's also using `new Date().getTime()` which there's no reason to use as the time is passed into `requestAnimationFrame`. It's calling some function to get a webgl context but there's no reason for that either in 2020. It's also apparently using an old version of glMatrix because [the current version](http://glmatrix.net/) uses a different API. In the current version every function takes a matrix to store the result as the first argument. Also in the current version `perspective` takes the field of view in radians. I have no idea if it used to take it in degrees but the code was passing degrees.

I changed the XHR code to just return a cube. (an example of the minimal and complete parts of an "minimal complete verifiable example" (mcve) - I think now S.O calls them a "minimal reproducible example". I also removed all the references to `ColorPicker` (another example of making a minimal repo)

The code should have gotten errors in [the JavaScript console](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console). Did you check the JavaScript console? In particular `uNMatrix` is a mat3 but the code was calling `gl.uniformMatrix4fv` to set it which is an error.

Using [webgl-lint](https://github.com/greggman/webgl-lint) pointed out several uniforms were not being set including "ambientProduct", "diffuseProduct", "specularProduct" and several were being set that don't exist (that part is not a bug necessarily) but there are several uniforms in the vertex shader that are not actually used and for example the colors seem to be set with

```
gl.uniform4fv(prg.uMaterialAmbient, object.ambient);
gl.uniform4fv(prg.uMaterialDiffuse, object.diffuse);
gl.uniform4fv(prg.uMaterialSpecular, object.specular);
```

but those uniforms are not used in the shaders (they appear in the shader but if you look at the code you'll see the effect nothing)

Then, when I finally got rid of all the errors the remaining issue to get something on the screen was the math for `gl_Position` had the 2 matrices backward. It should be `projection * modelView * position` but it had `modelView * projection * position`

But, further, all 3 models are drawn at the same position. Maybe the geometry in those models are at different positions. I have no idea but normally you'd want to give each thing you draw it's own position in some form or another, based on the loop index or some array of positions or per object data.

Anyway, that gets something on the screen but having spent 45 minutes already I don't feel like trying to fix the lighting. Rather, I suggest you read some slightly more up to date tutorials like [this one](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-lighting-point.html) and the ones it links to.

```js
var mat4 = glMatrix.mat4;
var gl = null; // WebGL context
var prg = null; // The program (shaders)
var c_width = 480; // Variable to store the width of the canvas
var c_height = 400; // Variable to store the height of the canvas

var mvMatrix = mat4.create(); // The Model-View matrix
var pMatrix = mat4.create(); // The projection matrix
var nMatrix = mat4.create(); // The normal matrix

var distance = -40;
var animateFlag = false;

var objects = [];

const utils = {
  getShader(gl, id) {
    const elem = document.getElementById(id);
    const type = /vertex/.test(elem.type) ?
      gl.VERTEX_SHADER :
      gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER;
    const sh = gl.createShader(type);
    gl.shaderSource(sh, elem.text);
    gl.compileShader(sh);
    if (!gl.getShaderParameter(sh, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
      throw new Error(gl.getShaderInfoLog(sh));
    }
    return sh;
  },
};

/**
 * The program contains a series of instructions that tell the Graphic Processing Unit (GPU)
 * what to do with every vertex and fragment that we pass it. 
 * The vertex shader and the fragment shader together are called the program.
 */
function initProgram() {
  var fragmentShader = utils.getShader(gl, "shader-fs");
  var vertexShader = utils.getShader(gl, "shader-vs");

  prg = gl.createProgram();
  gl.attachShader(prg, vertexShader);
  gl.attachShader(prg, fragmentShader);
  gl.linkProgram(prg);

  if (!gl.getProgramParameter(prg, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
    alert("Could not initialise shaders");
  }

  gl.useProgram(prg);

  prg.aVertexPosition = gl.getAttribLocation(prg, "aVertexPosition");
  prg.aVertexNormal = gl.getAttribLocation(prg, "aVertexNormal");

  prg.uPMatrix = gl.getUniformLocation(prg, "uPMatrix");
  prg.uMVMatrix = gl.getUniformLocation(prg, "uMVMatrix");
  prg.uNMatrix = gl.getUniformLocation(prg, "uNMatrix");


  prg.uMaterialAmbient = gl.getUniformLocation(prg, "uMaterialAmbient");
  prg.uMaterialDiffuse = gl.getUniformLocation(prg, "uMaterialDiffuse");
  prg.uMaterialSpecular = gl.getUniformLocation(prg, "uMaterialSpecular");
  prg.uShininess = gl.getUniformLocation(prg, "uShininess");


  prg.uLightPosition = gl.getUniformLocation(prg, "uLightPosition");
  prg.uLightAmbient = gl.getUniformLocation(prg, "uLightAmbient");
  prg.uLightDiffuse = gl.getUniformLocation(prg, "uLightDiffuse");
  prg.uLightSpecular = gl.getUniformLocation(prg, "uLightSpecular");
  
  prg.ambientProduct = gl.getUniformLocation(prg, "ambientProduct");
  prg.diffuseProduct = gl.getUniformLocation(prg, "diffuseProduct");
  prg.specularProduct = gl.getUniformLocation(prg, "specularProduct");
}


function initLights() {
  //Light uniforms
  gl.uniform3fv(prg.uLightPosition, [4.5, 3.0, 15.0]);
  gl.uniform4f(prg.uLightAmbient, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
  gl.uniform4f(prg.uLightDiffuse, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
  gl.uniform4f(prg.uLightSpecular, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

  //Object Uniforms
  gl.uniform4f(prg.uMaterialAmbient, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1.0);
  gl.uniform4f(prg.uMaterialDiffuse, 0.5, 0.8, 0.1, 1.0);
  gl.uniform4f(prg.uMaterialSpecular, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 1.0);
  gl.uniform1f(prg.uShininess, 200.0);
}


/**
 * Creates an AJAX request to load the scene asynchronously
 */
function loadScene() {
  loadObject('models/plane.json');
  loadObject('models/cone.json', 'cone');
  loadObject('models/sphere.json', 'sphere');
  loadObject('models/smallsph.json', 'lightsource');
}

function getObject(alias) {
  for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
    if (alias == objects[i].alias) return objects[i];
  }
  return null;
}

/**
 * Ajax and JSON in action
 */

const vertices = [
  -1, -1,  1,
   1, -1,  1,
  -1,  1,  1,
   1,  1,  1,
   1, -1,  1,
   1, -1, -1,
   1,  1,  1,
   1,  1, -1,
   1, -1, -1, 
  -1, -1, -1,
   1,  1, -1, 
  -1,  1, -1,
  -1, -1, -1,
  -1, -1,  1,
  -1,  1, -1,
  -1,  1,  1,
   1,  1, -1,
  -1,  1, -1,
   1,  1,  1,
  -1,  1,  1,
   1, -1,  1,
  -1, -1,  1,
   1, -1, -1,
  -1, -1, -1,
];
let modelNum = 0
function loadObject(filename, alias) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    const o = {
      alias: (alias == null) ? 'none' : alias,
      ambient: [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1],
      diffuse: [Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), 1],
      specular: [1, 1, 1, 1],
      // to make up for the fact the code does not have different positions
      // for each model we'll move the vertices (bad)
      vertices: vertices.map((v, i) => i % 3 === 0 ? v + modelNum * 3 : v),
      indices: [
        0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3,
        4, 5, 6, 6, 5, 7,
        8, 9, 10, 10, 9, 11,
        12, 13, 14, 14, 13, 15,
        16, 17, 18, 18, 17, 19,
        20, 21, 22, 22, 21, 23,
      ],
    };
    handleLoadedObject(filename, o);
    ++modelNum;
  });
}

/**
 * Creates the buffers that contain the geometry of the object
 */
function handleLoadedObject(filename, object) {

  //console.info(filename + ' has been retrieved from the server');

  var vertexBufferObject = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferObject);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(object.vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);


  var normalBufferObject = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, normalBufferObject);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(calcNormals(object.vertices, object.indices)), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

  var indexBufferObject = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBufferObject);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(object.indices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);


  object.vbo = vertexBufferObject;
  object.ibo = indexBufferObject;
  object.nbo = normalBufferObject;

  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);

  objects.push(object);
}

/**
 * Main rendering function. Called every 500ms according to WebGLStart function (see below)
 */
function drawScene() {
  gl.clearColor(0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1.0);
  //gl.clearDepth(100.0);
  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
  gl.depthFunc(gl.LEQUAL);
  gl.viewport(0, 0, c_width, c_height);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  mat4.perspective(pMatrix, 60 * Math.PI / 180, c_width / c_height, 0.1, 1000.0);

  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(prg.aVertexPosition);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(prg.aVertexNormal);
  for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
    var object = objects[i];
    mat4.identity(mvMatrix);
    mat4.translate(mvMatrix, mvMatrix, [0.0, 0.0, distance]); //Sets the camera to a reasonable distance to view the part
    mat4.rotate(mvMatrix, mvMatrix, 30 * Math.PI / 180, [1, 0, 0]);
    mat4.rotate(mvMatrix, mvMatrix, angle * Math.PI / 180, [0, 1, 0]);
    if (object.alias == 'lightsource') {
      var lightPos = gl.getUniform(prg, prg.uLightPosition);
      mat4.translate(mvMatrix, mvMatrix, lightPos);

    }

    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(prg.uMVMatrix, false, mvMatrix);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(prg.uPMatrix, false, pMatrix);
    mat4.set(mvMatrix, nMatrix);
    mat4.invert(nMatrix, nMatrix);
    mat4.transpose(nMatrix, nMatrix);

    const t3 = glMatrix.mat3.create();
    glMatrix.mat3.fromMat4(t3, nMatrix);
    gl.uniformMatrix3fv(prg.uNMatrix, false, t3);
    gl.uniform4fv(prg.ambientProduct, object.ambient);
    gl.uniform4fv(prg.diffuseProduct, object.diffuse);
    gl.uniform4fv(prg.specularProduct, object.specular);
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, object.vbo);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(prg.aVertexPosition, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(prg.aVertexPosition);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, object.nbo);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(prg.aVertexNormal, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(prg.aVertexNormal);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, object.ibo);
    gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, object.indices.length, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
  }
}

var lastTime = 0;
var angle = 0;
/**
 * Updates the angle of rotation by a little bit each time
 */
function animate() {
  var timeNow = new Date().getTime();
  if (lastTime != 0) {
    var elapsed = timeNow - lastTime;
    if (animateFlag) angle += (90 * elapsed) / 10000.0;
  }
  lastTime = timeNow;
}

/**
 * Render Loop
 */
function renderLoop() {
  drawScene();
  animate();
  requestAnimationFrame(renderLoop);
}

/**
 * Entry point. This function is invoked when the page is loaded
 */
function runWebGLApp() {
  //Obtains a WebGL context
  gl = document.getElementById("canvas-element-id").getContext('webgl');
  //Initializes the program (shaders) 
  initProgram();
  //Initializes lights
  initLights();
  //Load Scene
  loadScene();
  //Renders the scene!
  renderLoop();
}

$('#slider-shininess').slider({
  value: 200,
  min: 1,
  max: 300,
  step: 1,
  slide: updateShininess
});
$('#slider-x').slider({
  value: 4.5,
  min: -50,
  max: 50,
  step: 0.1,
  slide: updateLightPosition,
  change: updateLightPosition
});
$('#slider-y').slider({
  value: 3.0,
  min: 0,
  max: 50,
  step: 0.1,
  slide: updateLightPosition,
  change: updateLightPosition
});
$('#slider-z').slider({
  value: 15.0,
  min: -50,
  max: 50,
  step: 0.1,
  slide: updateLightPosition,
  change: updateLightPosition
});


$('#animate-btn').button();
$('#animate-btn').click(
  function() {
    if ($('#animate-btn:checked').val() == null) {
      animateFlag = false;
    } else {
      animateFlag = true;
    }
  });

function updateShininess() {
  var v = $('#slider-shininess').slider("value");
  gl.uniform1f(prg.uShininess, v);
  $('#slider-shininess-value').html(v);
}



function updateLightPosition() {
  var x = $('#slider-x').slider("value");
  var y = $('#slider-y').slider("value");
  var z = $('#slider-z').slider("value");
  gl.uniform3fv(prg.uLightPosition, [x, y, z]);
  $('#slider-x-value').html(x);
  $('#slider-y-value').html(y);
  $('#slider-z-value').html(z);
}


function updateDistance() {
  var d = $('#slider-distance').slider("value");
  $('#slider-distance-value').html(distance);
  distance = -d;
}



function updateObjectColor(alias, r, g, b) {
  var object = getObject(alias);
  if (object != null) {
    object.diffuse = [r, g, b, 1.0];
  }

}

// Calcule les normales des vertex. La normale de chaque vertex est
// la moyenne des triangles voisins.
//
// vertices: la liste des vertex.
// ind: la liste des indices.
// retour: la liste des normales par vertex.
function calcNormals(vertices, ind) {
  var x = 0;
  var y = 1;
  var z = 2;
  var v1 = [],
    v2 = [],
    thisNormal = [];

  // initialiser la liste des normales.
  var ns = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++) {
    ns[i] = 0.0;
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < ind.length; i = i + 3) {
    //v1 = p1 - p0
    v1[x] = vertices[3 * ind[i + 1] + x] - vertices[3 * ind[i] + x];
    v1[y] = vertices[3 * ind[i + 1] + y] - vertices[3 * ind[i] + y];
    v1[z] = vertices[3 * ind[i + 1] + z] - vertices[3 * ind[i] + z];

    // v2 = p2 - p1
    v2[x] = vertices[3 * ind[i + 2] + x] - vertices[3 * ind[i] + x];
    v2[y] = vertices[3 * ind[i + 2] + y] - vertices[3 * ind[i] + y];
    v2[z] = vertices[3 * ind[i + 2] + z] - vertices[3 * ind[i] + z];

    // N = v2 x v1 (cross product).
    thisNormal[x] = v1[y] * v2[z] - v1[z] * v2[y];
    thisNormal[y] = v1[z] * v2[x] - v1[x] * v2[z];
    thisNormal[z] = v1[x] * v2[y] - v1[y] * v2[x];

    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      // N += thisNormal. on additionne les normales. 
      ns[3 * ind[i + j] + x] = ns[3 * ind[i + j] + x] + thisNormal[x];
      ns[3 * ind[i + j] + y] = ns[3 * ind[i + j] + y] + thisNormal[y];
      ns[3 * ind[i + j] + z] = ns[3 * ind[i + j] + z] + thisNormal[z];
    }
  }

  // Normalisation.
  for (var i = 0; i < vertices.length; i = i + 3) {

    var nn = [];
    var len = 0;
    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      nn[j] = ns[i + j];
      len += nn[j] * nn[j];
    }

    // La norme de la normale.
    len = Math.sqrt(len);
    if (len == 0)
      len = 0.00001;

    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++)
      ns[i + j] = nn[j] / len;
  }

  return ns;
}

runWebGLApp();
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script id="shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
    attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;
    attribute vec3 aVertexNormal;

    // matrice model-view combinee.
    uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;

    // matrice de projection
    uniform mat4 uPMatrix;

    // matrice des normales.
    uniform mat3 uNMatrix;

    // position de la lumiere.
    uniform vec3 uLightPosition;

    // La normale transformee
    varying vec3 vNormal;

    // la direction vertex-lumiere
    varying vec3 vLightRay;

    // la direction camera-vertex
    varying vec3 vEyeVec;

    uniform vec4 uLightAmbient;
    uniform vec4 uLightDiffuse;
    uniform vec4 uLightSpecular;

    uniform vec4 uMaterialAmbient;
    uniform vec4 uMaterialDiffuse;
    uniform vec4 uMaterialSpecular;


    void main(void) {


    vec4 ambientProduct= uLightAmbient* uMaterialAmbient;
    vec4 diffuseProduct= uLightDiffuse*uMaterialDiffuse;
    vec4 specularProduct= uLightSpecular*uMaterialSpecular;

    vec3 pos = (uMVMatrix*vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0)).xyz;


    // position de l'oeil/camera.
    const vec3 eyePosition = vec3(0,0,-40);

    //Transformed normal position
    vNormal = normalize((uNMatrix* aVertexNormal).xyz) ;

    //Transformed light position
    vec4 light = uMVMatrix * vec4(uLightPosition,1.0);

    vec3 lightPos = (uMVMatrix * light).xyz;

    //Light position
    vLightRay = normalize(pos - lightPos);

    //Vector Eye
    vEyeVec = -normalize(pos);


    //Final vertex position
    gl_Position = uPMatrix*uMVMatrix* vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);

    }
</script>

<script id="shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
    #ifdef GL_ES
    precision highp float;
    #endif

    varying vec3 vNormal;
    varying vec3 vLightRay;
    varying vec3 vEyeVec;

    uniform vec4 ambientProduct;
    uniform vec4 diffuseProduct;
    uniform vec4 specularProduct;
    uniform float uShininess;

    void main(void)
    {

    vec4 diffuse = max(dot( vNormal,vLightRay), 0.0) * diffuseProduct;
    vec3 H = normalize(vLightRay+vEyeVec);
    vec4 specular =
    pow(max(dot(vNormal, H), 0.0), uShininess) * specularProduct;
    if (dot(vLightRay, vNormal) < 0.0)
    specular = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    vec4 fColor = ambientProduct + diffuse + specular;
    fColor.a = 1.0;
    gl_FragColor =fColor;

    }
</script>



<div id='top'>

<div id='contents'>
<div id='canvasContainer'>
<canvas id='canvas-element-id' width='480' height='400'>
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas element.
</canvas>
</div>
</div>

<div id='bottom'>
<table style='padding=0px'>
<tr>
<td>X:</td><td id='slider-x-value' width='30px'>4.5</td><td width='150px'><div id='slider-x'/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Y:</td><td id='slider-y-value'  width='30px'>3.0</td><td width='150px'><div id='slider-y'/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Z:</td> <td id='slider-z-value'  width='30px'>15.0</td><td width='150px'><div id='slider-z'/></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gl-matrix@3.3.0/gl-matrix-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://greggman.github.io/webgl-lint/webgl-lint.js"
  data-gman-debug-helper='
    {
      "warnUndefinedUniforms": false
    }
  '
></script>
```

Comment: If `No one uses XMLHttpRequest in 2020` how do you listen to `progress` event?

Comment: My guess would be something [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/greggman/axfb0tcp/)